# C struct question

Tags: c, struct

I have a interface documented like this:

```
typedef struct Tree {
  int a;
  void* (*Something)(struct Tree* pTree, int size);
};
```

Then as I understand I need to create instance of it, and use Something method to put the value for 'size'.
So I do

```
struct Tree *iTree = malloc(sizeof(struct Tree));
iTree->Something(iTree, 128);
```

But it keeps failing to initialize. Am I doing this right?
Howcome the first member of the Something method is pointer to the very same struct?

Can anyone explain please?

Thanks

Comment: There is not much C++ in this question. You might consider removing the tag or get answers like Ben's.

Comment: I can't get one thing: what's the purpose of that typedef?

Comment: You will want to remove the typedef unless you name the structure by moving `Tree` to the end between `}` and `;`. ^ @sidyll +1 Your comment showed up after I posted this.

Comment: No problem @Joe, and thanks by the way. I thought it would be some special addition from C++ , as it doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @pmr: I'd give the same answer to the `c` tag: It's emulating a C++ virtual function without language support.

Comment: btw, your typedef won't work. You're not typedef'ing as anything.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to set `Something` to something since it is only a function pointer and not a function. The struct you created with malloc just contains garbage and struct fields need to be set before it is useful.

```
struct Tree *iTree = malloc(sizeof(struct Tree));
iTree->a = 10; //<-- Not necessary to work but you should set the values.
iTree->Something = SomeFunctionMatchingSomethingSignature;
iTree->Something(iTree, 128);
```

**Update**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct Tree {
    int a;
    //This is a function pointer
    void* (*Something)(struct Tree* pTree, int size);
};

//This is a function that matches Something signature
void * doSomething(struct Tree *pTree, int size)
{
    printf("Doing Something: %d\n", size);
    return NULL;
}

void someMethod()
{
    //Code to create a Tree
    struct Tree *iTree = malloc(sizeof(struct Tree));
    iTree->Something = doSomething;
    iTree->Something(iTree, 128);
    free(iTree);
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind a function pointer is just that, a pointer. It needs to reference a function somewhere.

Comment: :/ I don't understand... what is SomeFunctionMatchingSomethingSignature ??

Answer (score 4):

This is a poor man's virtual function.  The initial parameter is roughly equivalent to C++'s `this` pointer in a member function.  And you must manually set the function pointers before calling them, whereas C++ virtual functions are set up by the compiler.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. While it's marked C/C++, it's clearly a C question since it's failing.

Comment: can you please give me example? Thanks!

Comment: @Dylan: What part of ***you must manually set the function pointers before calling them*** doesn't answer the question?

Comment: I mean, it seems superfluous to mention the comparison to a C++ virtual method, because, it's not. It's a C function pointer in a C structure.

Comment: @Dylan: Which is what you use when you want a virtual function, but you're stuck with C.

Comment: This question is not tagged as a C++ question, it's a C question. Please answer it as such. C and C++ are not the same language.

Comment: It was originally tagged `c++`.  As far as I know, the OP still wants it tagged `c++` (someone else edited it).  And it any case, understanding that this is used to provide polymorphism akin to a C++ virtual function is important.

Answer (score 1):

The member `Tree::Something` is never initialized. You allocate space for a `Tree`, but allocation is different from initialization, and your allocated `Tree` contains only unmeaningful bits.